Alternative to std::function that returns object with deleted copy operator
In my code HeavyObjectManager generates instances of HeavyObject (which should never be copied), and i tried to make generation itself be customizeable by passing HeavyObjectGenerator function.
class HeavyObject {
    int x;
public:
    HeavyObject(int x) : x(x) {}

    HeavyObject &operator=(const HeavyObject &) = delete;
    HeavyObject &operator=(HeavyObject &&) = delete;
};

using HeavyObjectGenerator = std::function<HeavyObject(int)>;

class HeavyObjectManager {
    HeavyObjectGenerator heavyObjectGenerator;

    HeavyObject heavyObject{0};
public:
    void updateHeavyObject(int x) {
        heavyObject = heavyObjectGenerator(x);
    }
    HeavyObjectManager(HeavyObjectGenerator gen) : heavyObjectGenerator(gen) {}
};

The problem is that this code needs HeavyObject to have copy operator.
Which makes sense because std::function doesn't know, maby I will try to return reference in HeavyObjectGenerator and it will need copy constructor.
But in practice, I want HeavyObjectGenerator to just construct HeavyObject inside it and immediately return it, which won't need copy operator nor move operator
What are my alternatives to implement what I want?

heavyObject =  is always either copy or move. What you want is unreachable in the shown code design. You can change the member and the function return value to std::unique_ptr<HeavyObject>.

@273K what i mean is that when you call usual function, it will use return value optimization, and "copy elision" (not sure it's correct to call it this way).
With what i'm trying to do, is it impossible?

See Copy elision: In the initialization of an object, Your case is not initialization, it's assignment.

Having a deleted move is very unusual, but If all else fails, allocate the object on the heap and handle it through a (smart) pointer.

But even if move operator won't be deleted it still won't work with std::function

This is because the default move assignment operator is deleted. Define a user one explicitly defaulted.

Oh i already forgot that they are implicitly removed.. Thank you

"Which makes sense because std::function doesn't know, maby i will try to return reference in HeavyObjectGenerator and it will need copy constructor." -- This does not follow. The std::function constructor (and assignment) does know and will block such construction/assignment if you try to return a reference (in whatever you are constructing/assigning from).

I understand why you would like to prevent copy of a HeavyObject because of efficiency reasons. But why do you want to prevent a move ?

std::function does work with movable return types, it's movable functors that it can't handle

I assume your "real" code doesn't expose public constructors for HeavyObject, else I don't see the point of this generator.

As a side note, if you can require C++23, you can use std::move_only_function.
